# Can't print string, keep getting not callable error

Tags: python

So this is the code:

```
def variousScores(students):
    best = 0
    worst = 100
    average = 0
    count = 0
    for s in students:
        if s.examScore > best:
            best = s.examScore
        if s.examScore < worst:
            worst = s.examScore
        average = s.examScore + average
        count = count + 1
    average = average/count
    return best, worst, average

def printScores(best, worst, average, stndrdDev):
    print("\n\nWorst score:        {:4.2f}.format"(worst))
```

I keep getting `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` at the line `print("\n\nWorst score:        {:4.2f}.format"(worst))`
I've only just started working with classes and I feel that is what is screwing me up.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Your current code is trying to call the string `"\n\nWorst score:        {:4.2f}.format"` as a function since you placed `(worst)` after it.

The last line should be written like this:

```
print("\n\nWorst score:        {:4.2f}".format(worst))
```

Notice that the `.format` part is on the *outside* of the format string.  This is because [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is a string method.